# "You should go" vs "You should have to go"

Tags: meaning, grammar, difference

What's the difference between:

> You should go

and

> You should have to go

Can I use one instead of the other?

Answer (score 2):

[should](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/should) means  "the correct or best thing to do". [have to](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have-to) means "to need to or be forced to; must".

> You should go

means that going is the best thing to do.

> You should have to go

means that the best thing would be if you were forced to go.

As you can see, the two are not interchangeable.